# How to hide and simultaneously show another section (similar to an accordion)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need some help creating something similar to an accordion. The goal is that if you click a link in the navigation the one section disappears and the one you clicked appears (at the same position and unnoticeable).
If possible it should also automatically scroll to the start of the section(end of the navigation).

Any advice or starting point?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/3dc548a9/15/)

```js
$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 50;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

body {
  height: 300vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  top: 2vh;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 0.25vw;
  padding: 0.25vw;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#navbar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#navwrapper {
    background: linear-gradient(250deg, #0061ff, #60efff);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    height: 250px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 130px;
  line-height: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightgray !important;  
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 1.5vh;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink a {
  color: #343a40 !important;
}

#navbar.shrink a:after {    
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #343a40 !important;
}

#navbar.shrink h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #343a40;
  top: 2vh;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
  <nav id="navwrapper">
    <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top">
      <h1 id="titel">HEADLINE</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" class="nav-link">
            <h2>content1</h2>
          </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#wir-ueber-uns" class="nav-link">
            <h2>content2</h2>
          </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#aktionen" class="nav-link">
            <h2>content3</h2>
          </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#terminvereinbarung" class="nav-link">
            <h2>content4</h2>
          </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#infos" class="nav-link">
            <h2>content5</h2>
          </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <section id="content1">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="content2">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="content3">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="content4">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section id="content5">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: What have you tried in your code? All i see is a scroll event which has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I don't really know how to start. My first guess would be to simply hide/show the section when clicked on a link

Comment: You could use `classList.toggle` for something like that. `onClick` event with a `toggle` will either remove a class or add it if doesn't exist. then you can do all sorts of things with that class to fit your needs.

Comment: ok so basically you need and Event Listener to click each  nav links so check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach ...so you would do a `forEach` for all `.nav-link a` ..same for the sections and toggle 'active' on both sections

Comment: Thank you I will look into that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is helps. It took me hours to pull it off. Searching even here at stackoverflow

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <title>Menu animation using javascript</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <style>
 #navi{
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
     left: 3%;
     width: 25%;
 }

 .menuItem{
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     width: 100%;
 }

 .menuPage{
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     background-color: #dcdcdc;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 2px 4px;
 }
 </style>

 <body>

 <div id="navi">

     <div id="Ldon" class="menuItem" onclick="openCity('London', 'Ldon')"><p class="menuPage">London</p>
         <div id="London" class="city" style="display:none">
             <h2>London</h2>
             <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div id="Pris" class="menuItem" onclick="openCity('Paris', 'Pris')"><p class="menuPage">Paris</p>
         <div id="Paris" class="city" style="display:none">
             <h2>Paris</h2>
             <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
         </div>
     </div>

     <div id="Tkyo" class="menuItem" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', 'Tkyo')"><p class="menuPage">Tokyo</p>
         <div id="Tokyo" class="city" style="display:none">
             <h2>Tokyo</h2>
             <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
         </div>
     </div>

 </div>

 <script>
 function openCity(cityName, newPos) {
 var i;
 var y = document.getElementsByClassName("menuItem");
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
 var moevePos = document.getElementById(newPos);

 for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
     y[i].style.position = "";  
     y[i].style.top = ""; 
 }

 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
 }

 document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";  
 moevePos.style.position = "absolute";
 moevePos.style.top = "80px";
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much for your time! It works great!